# How can I find out whether an NSDate is a business day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nslocale

How can I find out whether an `NSDate` is a business day?  That is to say, whether or not it is a weekend according to the user's current locale and calendar settings - so not hardcoded to just be Monday to Friday?

`NSCalendar` has a `firstWeekday` property, but that just seems to be a presentational thing; it's Sunday in the US and Monday in the UK.

EDIT: I'm not worried about holidays, I just want to be able to shade the weekends of a calendar in the same way as the built-in calendar app.

Comment: Are there cultures where Monday to Friday are not the only business days?

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend

Answer (score 5):

**Update for iOS 8 and higher:**

`NSCalendar` now contains method [- (BOOL)isDateInWeekend:(NSDate *)date](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDateInWeekend:)

which checks whether a date falls under weekend in a particular calendar & locale.

**Old answer**

If you only need to shade the weekends, `[NSDateComponents weekday]` is your friend. This method will return 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday.

Fact: Most applications assume weekend = Saturday & Sunday. AFAIK this is correct for all countries using Gregorian Calendar. The only possibility covering all other calendars is to have a local database per calendar/locale and watch for changes. If such a change happens an application update is needed or new data has to be downloaded.

If we are talking about business days (not only weekends), we are talking about something that

1. has no clear definition (what is a business day changes between companies)
2. has no specification (for example - date formatting, time zones etc. has internationally accepted specifications)
3. is often changed by local law (e.g. holidays added)

What you need is to let the users set up your applications for their individual needs, depending on their nationality and employer.

Comment: But which days are the weekends? It's not always Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: @Simon See the first part of my answer. There is no definition or standard so it's not accessible by locale. Most applications assume weekend is always equal to Saturday & Sunday.

Comment: The built-in calendar manages somehow, so it must be possible.

Comment: @Simon Of course, if you have something that is often synchronized with a server which contains a database, then it's possible.

Comment: Surely that's how all the NSLocale keys have to work, though; the handset must have a big DB of per-locale settings which is periodically updated. That doesn't make it impossible; it just means that they've designed things badly if there are two separate DBs, one for NSLocale and one for the calendar app.

Comment: @simon You dont see the difference. Locales are standardized. Weekends are not. They are not a part of common language/region settings. Thats why it would be hard to provide a public API.

Comment: How are weekends not standardised?  It varies from country to country, same as other locale settings, but I don't see evidence of anywhere where it moves around within the week.

Comment: @Simon It doesn't only vary from country to country, it varies from person from person (if we are speaking about bussiness/working days). Standard is a type of official document. There is no standard for "weekend" or "bussiness day". That's a fact. Accept it.

Comment: No, that's nonsense. Calendar.app doesn't vary which days are weekends from person to person, because weekends don't vary from person to person.

Comment: @Simon I was talking about bussiness days. The developers of Calendar app just made a subjective non-standard decision, created a (small) database and that's it. What do you expect?

Comment: What makes you think it's a subjective non-standard decision? Can you back that up rather than just asserting it?

Comment: @Simon Yes. I can back up it by the fact there is no standard defining "weekends". Hence every software that is not using weekends as a synonym for Sat & Sun is non-standard. I am done with this discussion. I have explained everything and I am not in the mood to repeat myself 3 times.

Comment: If you can back it up, great - please do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get if the day is Monday to Friday, but as far as I know, there's no such things as business day for NSDate depending on the location, as for example firstWeekday, so you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Weekday: %d", dateComponents.weekday);
```

This will also differentiate whether the device is in a territory where Sunday or Monday are considered to be the first day of the week.

Comment: I understand how to find what weekday it is.  I need to know whether that weekday is a business day according to the user's locale settings.