# How to get weekends vs weekdays in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, locale, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

What is the correct calendar-agnostic way (in either iOS or OS X) to get standard business days of the week (e.g. weekdays) versus non-working days of the week? This is taking into account that [some parts of the world doesn't follow the Monday through Friday working day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend) routine. E.g. the UAE and some parts of Malaysia works from Sunday through Thursday.

I'm looking to emulate iOS' built-in Alarm application in which if I select a repeating day of Monday through Friday, it will say that my alarm repeats "Weekdays" whereas for alarms that fires on Saturday and Sunday says "Weekends". However, I'd like my app to also work correctly in other parts of the world that doesn't follow the western world's work week.

I've been toying around with `NSCalendar`'s `isDateInWeekend` function with various other calendars and haven't been able to find a good method to determine weekday vs weekend. Here's a snippet from a Swift playground that I got so far:

```swift
import UIKit

let arabicLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_AR")
let islamicTabularCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicTabular)
islamicTabularCalendar?.locale = arabicLocale
let islamicTabularFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
islamicTabularFormatter.calendar = islamicTabularCalendar
islamicTabularFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
gregorianCalendar?.locale = arabicLocale
let gregorianFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
gregorianFormatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar
gregorianFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

let monday = NSDateComponents()
monday.weekday = 2
monday.weekOfMonth = 0
let friday = NSDateComponents()
friday.weekday = 6
friday.weekOfMonth = 0

let mondayDate = islamicTabularCalendar?.dateFromComponents(monday)
gregorianFormatter.stringFromDate(mondayDate!)          // "Monday, July 8, 622"
islamicTabularFormatter.stringFromDate(mondayDate!)     // "Monday, Dhuʻl-Hijjah 20, 0 AH"
islamicTabularCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(mondayDate!)    // false

let fridayDate = islamicTabularCalendar?.dateFromComponents(friday)
gregorianFormatter.stringFromDate(fridayDate!)          // Friday, July 12, 622
islamicTabularFormatter.stringFromDate(fridayDate!)     // Friday, Dhuʻl-Hijjah 24, 0 AH
islamicTabularCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(fridayDate!)    // false
```

What I'm looking for is something that returns `false` for Fridays in parts of the world that practices Monday-Friday working days but returns `true` for UAE and the like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out whether an NSDate is a business day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546017/how-can-i-find-out-whether-an-nsdate-is-a-business-day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. The mistake was in the locale identifier which should be `en_AE` instead of `en_AR`

```
import UIKit

let arabicLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_AE")
let islamicTabularCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicTabular)
islamicTabularCalendar?.locale = arabicLocale
let islamicTabularFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
islamicTabularFormatter.calendar = islamicTabularCalendar
islamicTabularFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
gregorianCalendar?.locale = arabicLocale
let gregorianFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
gregorianFormatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar
gregorianFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

let monday = NSDateComponents()
monday.weekday = 2
monday.weekOfMonth = 0
let friday = NSDateComponents()
friday.weekday = 6
friday.weekOfMonth = 0

let mondayDate = islamicTabularCalendar?.dateFromComponents(monday)
gregorianFormatter.stringFromDate(mondayDate!)          // "Monday, July 8, 622"
islamicTabularFormatter.stringFromDate(mondayDate!)     // "Monday, Dhuʻl-Hijjah 20, 0 AH"
islamicTabularCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(mondayDate!)    // false
gregorianCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(mondayDate!)         // false

let fridayDate = islamicTabularCalendar?.dateFromComponents(friday)
gregorianFormatter.stringFromDate(fridayDate!)          // Friday, July 12, 622
islamicTabularFormatter.stringFromDate(fridayDate!)     // Friday, Dhuʻl-Hijjah 24, 0 AH
islamicTabularCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(fridayDate!)    // true
gregorianCalendar?.isDateInWeekend(fridayDate!)         // false
```